# Automating Find & Replace to change font colour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I write about the card game bridge, so I need to automate this formatting all the time:

Find all "♣" and color the text green (#00b700).
Find all "♦" and color the text orange (#ff8100).
Find all "♥" and color the text red (#ff0000).
Find all "♠" and color the text blue (#0000ff).

[Screenshot of what the script should do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ans5D.jpg).

@Mark built me a script to do this, but I'm getting this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot find function setFontColor in object Text."

[Would someone please have a look at the script and try to spot the solution? Thanks](https://pastebin.com/YX5eFDy4)

Comment: Please a add a brief description of you search/research efforts made regarding fixing the referred error message as we as adding the textual error message (the code line number is missing). A good practice is to create a minimal complete example and add the code to the question as the external resource could be unavailable in the future.

Comment: Hi @Rubén. This has now been solved (see update above). My search/research efforts included hours of googling, trawling forums and stackexchange and reading tutorials. It took about twenty hours to solve, but I'll get that time back ten-fold by the amount of time I can now save working quickly from any location, and sharing the solution with other bridge pros.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has now been solved. To see how the solution was built, or to get a copy of the Script [click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119174/how-can-i-automate-find-replace-to-change-font-colours-in-google-docs/).

Answer (score -1):

```
function testColor() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♣')
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♣')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♣')
  .setFontColor('#FF0000')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(10, 9).activate();
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getActiveRange()])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(10, 9).activate();
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-10, -9, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♦')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-10, -9, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♦')
  .setFontColor('#FFFF00')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell())
  .setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('♦')
  .setTextStyle(0, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
  .setForegroundColor('#000000')
  .build())
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 5).activate();
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getActiveRange()])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♥')
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♥')
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .setFontColor('#FF0000')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♥')
  .setFontColor('#FF0000')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♠')
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♠')
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .setFontColor('#FF0000')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1000, 26)])
  .whenTextContains('♠')
  .setFontColor('#FF0000')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
};
```